unlayer the html exported seems styleless when viewed
I am trying to export the HTML of a template to try and see if I can send an email that looks exactly like the template, however it seems I am missing something as the results looks styleless.
Here is the template example I am trying to extract the HTML from :

and here is the result in an online template viewer :

Is not everything in the data.html from the response of extractHTML? What am I missing here?

"as the results looks styleless" - how are the styles actually embedded into your HTML email?

What's your exact process for getting the HTML, and what program are you using to view it? What is "an online template viewer" -- why aren't you just using a straight html file direct from your local drive?
